# YouTube center extension for Chrome moves the video window to the right

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Google Chrome 32. I wanted to disable DASH (Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP) on YouTube and hence I installed the extension [YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki).

It did disable DASH but posed a few other problems:

- It moved the video window slightly to the right.
- It removed 1080p and 480p from the settings menu.

[image: window moved to the right]

[image: Quality options missing]

I want the default player size options that YouTube provides.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a bug in the extension. You should contact the developer directly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation? It states [here](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki/Features#wiki-dash-playback) that YouTube doesn't support 480p and 1080p with DASH disabled. [Apparently](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki/Features#wiki-dash-playback) the developer is working on that.

Of some reason the div #player is to small, I haven't managed to fix that through the settings, but you could download another extension ([Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) for example) fix that yourself, until the developer does something about that. Set the width to 1040 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom sizes in YoutubeCenter, just open YTcenter settings and navigate to Player/Player Size, press "Add Player Size" and give it the following dimensions: 390px by 621px, save the custom player with what ever name you want, select the custom size from the drop down menu thats to the right of "Default Player Size". Also make sure the first box is selected.

[image]

That should fix it.